# Buttons Shrink in a Relative Layout

Tags: android, imagebutton

how can i avoid this Shrink that happens in the last item?
[image]

i mean, i can add only 4 full ImageButtons, the other will SHRINK

the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background ="#88676767"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/text_bold"

            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton" />

       ..... others buttons

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:src="@drawable/text_foreground"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton4" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try to use LinearLayout and assign weight for each of the child views. If the weights are equal then all your buttons takes equal space.

Comment: I have tried your code but the buttons aren't shrinking ... Can you upload the whole code of relativeLayout ?
When I added the sixth button it did shrink that's because of the lack of space if you change the orientation it will also fit in

Comment: i was near to post when i tried to change to LINEARLAYOUT, and it really solved o0, thanks guys

Comment: use weights with the linear layout